# How to apply multiple filters using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am new to using the Graph API and trying to use the beta version to get user information and want to filter based on userType and signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime.  Individually the filters work fine on their own but together they error with a "filter not supported".  This happens in the Graph Explorer also but the documentation indicates I should be able to filter on more than one thing?  I can only think if it is a restriction of the signInActivity filter specifically that doesn't allow you to do another filter?

These both individually work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=userType eq 'Guest'&select=displayName,id

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime ge 2021-05-01T00:00:00Z&select=displayName,id
```

However the following does not work and returns a "Filter not supported" error:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime ge 2021-05-01T00:00:00Z and userType eq 'Guest'&select=displayName,id
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I see a similar question was asked here [Microsoft Graph - Error when using multiple filters for CalendarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087291/microsoft-graph-error-when-using-multiple-filters-for-calendarview) but no answer currently.

Comment: you are missing `$` before filter - `$filter`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but with the beta version the `$` is optional so it works with and without

Comment: Yeah, i agree with Steve with beta version it's optional. BTW what exact error you're getting along with the requestid, timestamp when you make the call?

Comment: Thanks - I get a http 400 response of BadRequest and message 'Filter not supported.'.  Sorry for asking, but how will the requestId and timestamp help?

Comment: As per a Microsoft Azure AD support engineer, this version currently in beta does not allow other filters with the signInActivity although if and when it is available in v1.0 (or a new version) they are assuming this functionality will be improved (I hope so)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this -- basically, to add multiple clauses to your $filter, simply add the word "and" to separate each criteria. this is the example I used and it seemed to work quite well:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(userPrincipalName,'mydomain.com') and accountEnabled eq false&$orderBy=userPrincipalName&$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,department,employeeid,jobtitle,accountEnabled
```

as it turns out, odata seems to not worry too much about spaces.

Comment: You're missing the point of the question here, the original question states that a filter on signInActivity cannot be combined with other clauses

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 filter types cannot be combined as of today.

I suggest pulling the data based on login and then reduce the list of last login down to Guests

```
- set_fact:  
    foo: "{{ bar | selectattr('userType', '==', 'Guest') | list }}"
```

On a sidenote: Thank you @soler - your answer helped me realize where I was screwing up a different filter statement.

Answer (score 0):

replacing spaces by %20 is working for me:

```
$filter=UserType%20eq%20'Guest'and%20signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime%20le%202021-04-26T17:30:09Z
```

Answer (score -3):

Found this post as I had the same issue.. adding the filter statement twice worked for me `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=UserType eq 'Guest'&$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-04-26T17:30:09Z&$select=displayName,UserType,signInActivity`

Comment: Thanks, I got excited by this but just tried with your example and I get the following error :- "Query option '$filter/filter' was specified more than once, but it must be specified at most once."